# On apply ng-if, it display none on another td??Why

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
th(data-toggle='true',data-sort-ignore="true",ng-if="#{user_type}==10") Organization
th(data-sort-ignore="true") Team Name
th(data-sort-ignore="true") Team Captain
```

apply ng-if, it hides the team captain th..plzz reply

Comment: What is this ? Please provide us the html

Comment: Can you update your question with valid code? It's not understandable at all.

Comment: <table data-page-size="5" class="footable table table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny team-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-toggle="true" data-sort-ignore="true" ng-if="user_type==10">Organization</th>
      <th data-sort-ignore="true">Team Name</th>
      <th data-sort-ignore="true">Team Captain</th>
      <th data-hide="all">Players</th>
      <th data-hide="all">Free Agents</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>    when i am applying ng-if on organization(th). then ng -if automatically hide the team caption(th). i want if i use ng-if then it does not hide the  team captain(th).